# How to config HTTPS on Apache tomcat

Tags: centos, ssl, certificates, https, tomcat

I have installed the Apache Tomcat/7.0.76 on centos7.
I want to enable SSL on the tomcat.
I have root, intermediate, domain certificate. Like this

85163c004aa3625d.crt
 gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
    gdig2.crt.pem 
   root.crt
 private.key

then I ran following commands,

keytool -import root -keystore testing.jks -trustcacerts -file tomcat/root.crt

keytool -import  -keystore testing.jks -trustcacerts -file tomcat/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt

keytool -import  -keystore testing.jks -trustcacerts -file tomcat/85163c004aa3625d.crt

Then I edited the server.xml as

<\Connector port="8443"
                protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                connectionTimeout="20000"
                redirectPort="8443"
                SSLEnabled="true"
                scheme="https"
                secure="true"
                sslProtocol="TLS"
                keystoreFile="/opt/tomcat/testingibay.jks"
                keystorePass="tomcat" \>

But then I saved that file and restarted tomcat service,
https://test.testing.local:8443 is not loading and however I can load the http://test.testing.local:8080

When I ran ./configtest.sh
it gives 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Jan 29, 2019 10:52:29 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol 
WARNING: The HTTP BIO connector has been removed in Tomcat 8.5.x onwards. The HTTP BIO connector configuration has been automatically switched to use the HTTP NIO connector instead.
Jan 29, 2019 10:52:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.37
Jan 29, 2019 10:52:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Dec 12 2018 12:07:02 UTC
Jan 29, 2019 10:52:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.5.37.0
Jan 29, 2019 10:52:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Linux
Jan 29, 2019 10:52:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64
Jan 29, 2019 10:52:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Jan 29, 2019 10:52:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.201-2.6.16.1.el7_6.x86_64/jre
Jan 29, 2019 10:52:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.7.0_201-mockbuild_2018_11_19_16_10-b00
Jan 29, 2019 10:52:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Jan 29, 2019 10:52:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/tomcat
Jan 29, 2019 10:52:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/tomcat
Jan 29, 2019 10:52:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
Jan 29, 2019 10:52:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
Jan 29, 2019 10:52:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
Jan 29, 2019 10:52:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
Jan 29, 2019 10:52:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
Jan 29, 2019 10:52:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat
Jan 29, 2019 10:52:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat
Jan 29, 2019 10:52:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temp
Jan 29, 2019 10:52:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
Jan 29, 2019 10:52:30 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jan 29, 2019 10:52:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol-8080]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol-8080]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:552)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:661)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:500)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:995)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:463)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:219)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1087)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:265)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:581)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:993)
        ... 13 more

Jan 29, 2019 10:52:30 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8443"]
Jan 29, 2019 10:52:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:552)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:661)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:500)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:995)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Alias name [null] does not identify a key entry
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:115)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:86)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:244)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1087)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:265)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:581)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:993)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Alias name [null] does not identify a key entry
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.getKeyManagers(JSSEUtil.java:261)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:113)
        ... 20 more

Jan 29, 2019 10:52:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jan 29, 2019 10:52:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:552)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:661)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:500)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:995)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:463)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:219)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1087)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:265)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:581)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:993)
        ... 13 more

Comment: I tried to save it as <Connector port... /> but it was failed ,please understand in my config file I saved it as  <Connector port... />

Comment: You have a BindException here. Is port 8443 already being used by another program?

Comment: how do I check that?

Comment: `ss -ltn` will show the ports currently listening. Look for port 8443 in that list.

Comment: I ran the command "ss -ltn | grep 8443" , but it did not show me any output

Comment: Did you run the 'configtest.sh' command while the server was up? It looks like it's trying to bind to the same ports as the running server.

Comment: It gives me <br>Failed to initialize connector [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol-8080]]<br>org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol-8080]]<br>Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed<br>Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use<br>. I think its give the same error again

Comment: (1) 'Address in use' is occurring on the _8080_ connector; look for another process using _that_ (2) The error for 8443 is 'not ... a key entry' because you didn't put the privatekey in the keystore. If it's an OpenSSL-supported format see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29603989/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37412374/ and additional dupes linked there, otherwise give details. (3) Also the filename in your connector doesn't match that in the keytool commands; if that's a true difference and not just a lie for posting, change it.

Comment: Thanks. I will test this and let u know the output